# Why is a jQuery Ajax post clearing all divs that have used load()?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, post

I am encountering a problem with using `$.ajax` to post a form. My application is an ImageMap and form prototype. I have a workflow that loads an image in a div from an image maps' click to an area on the map of countries. This image is of a country, another image map that accepts a click to a region on the map. This then shows my form.

All these operations show a result in a `div` on the one page, spaced around the page. My problem is the form submit. It is a simple form, and it gathers data from the database (at the moment only one record ) and fills a row for selective entry. This allows the data to be collected on the server side. All this sounds normal!

[Image of form on page through selection of Country](http://db.tt/qdsLdt6)

Yeah, this all displays. Bet, I have a `$.ajax` Post on the form, so it gets no refresh on the page after a page submit. And cool, it does post data to a PHP page (I checked the output), though? When it gets submitted the previously loaded country div is cleared of content. And any attempt to `load()` a new page or HTML in a `div` fails.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online Flights</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css" />
        <script src="lib/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('area').bind('click mouseover', function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var subStrEnd = id.length - 4;
                    var countryDiv = id.substring(0, subStrEnd);
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('#area2').load( href + ' #' + countryDiv).css({ opacity: 0 }).fadeTo("slow",1);
                    return false;
                });

                $('.countryItem').live('click', function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    $('#area3').load(id).css({ opacity: 0 }).fadeTo("slow",1);
                    return false;
                });

                $(".submitFlights").live('click', function() {
                    var name = 'testname';
                    var email = 'as@erdd.com';
                    var phone = '02987374754';
                    var dataString = 'action=add' + '&name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Pages/includes/area4.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function() {
                            // alert(dataString);
                            $('#area3').html("<h2>New Flight Requested</h2>");
                            $('#area3').show();
                            //  console.log($('#area4').html());
                            // alert(dataString);
                        }
                    });
                    $('#area4').load("Pages/includes/area4.php");
                    console.log($('#area4').html());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pageHeader">
            <img src="LogoSmall.png" alt="Logo">
            <img src="uluru.jpg" alt="Uluru">
            <img src="queensland.jpg" alt="Queensland">
            <img src="pelican.jpg" alt="Pelicans West Australia">
        </div>
        <div id="area1">
            <div style="text-align:center; width:350px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                <img id="wMap" src="WMGreen.png" usemap="#wMap" border="0" width="350" height="175" alt="" />
                <map id="_wMap" name="wMap">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="77,90,135,170"
                          id ="south_america_Lnk" href="Pages/includes/area2.php?image=SA"
                          alt="South America" title="South America"/>
                    <area shape="rect" coords="42,36,108,91" id ="north_america_Lnk"
                          href="Pages/includes/area2.php?image=NA"
                          alt="North America" title="North America" />
                </map>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="area2">
        </div>
        <div id="area3">
        </div>
        <div id="area4">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I use live for the loaded `div` area2 (that call ab event to load the `div` area3) and for the class of the submit button in area3.

Also, when I do a submit of the form the line flashes for a second then disapears with the loaded content in area 2.

```
$('#area3').html("<h2>New Flight Requested</h2>");
```

[Form submit, it cleared the divs, and failed on load new content into divs](http://db.tt/bBCQEBh)

### Problem 1

---

Why does the post of the form clear `div` area2 and `div` area3 both? Should it leave the content with just an Ajax post? Do I need to do something to keep the page content like cache?

### Problem 2

---

Why can't I load the data to `div` area4 and area3 after the Ajax form post? This is most troublesome.

I am new to this kind of jQuery coding, so I am unaware of any blunders I might be causing inadvertently.

Comment: Do you have a test page we can all look at? I reckon it might be easier to identify your problem

Comment: Hi Test page is http://objectseale.com/HWT/Index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: Click on a button with type 'submit' will submit a synchronous request(default html behavior), so the index.php will reload after form submits. Modify the type to 'button' or add event.preventDefault() before submiting.

```
    $(".submitFlights").live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /// .... others 
    });
```

Problem 2: the same to problem 1